# SAX parser issue

Tags: java, android, rss, sax

I am working on a RSS feed reader for a particular RSS feed, and I am having a problem with SAX and the  tag.  The tag looks like this

```
<description>
<![CDATA[<img src=http://www.lamaruniversitypress.com/polopoly_fs/1.1832584!image/2678128836.jpg_gen/thumbnails/100x100/2678128836.jpg><br /><br><p>
    South Korea vowed Wednesday to completely punish North Korea if it attacks again.
...</p>]]>
</description>
```

My startElement method has this element to handle the description tag looks like this:

```
if (localName.equals("description"))
        {            
            currentstate = RSS_DESCRIPTION;
            return;
        }
```

and my chars method looks like this:

```
case RSS_DESCRIPTION:
            _item.setDescription(theString);
            Log.i("DESCRIPTION","characters[" + theString + "]");
            currentstate = 0;
            break;
```

The log file displays this:

```
12-22 11:21:06.517: INFO/TITLE(489): characters[SKorea holds massive new drills after North attack]
12-22 11:21:06.527: INFO/DESCRIPTION(489): characters[
12-22 11:21:06.527: INFO/DESCRIPTION(489): ]
```

This is my first attempt at working with SAX, and I am getting pretty close to rewriting the whole thing with a different parser, asking you guys is my last ditch effort.

I have tried handling the paragraph tag, that does not work, presumably because it is inside of the CDATA.  I have attempted to substring the descriptions like this

```
String theString = new String(ch,start,length);
        /*
        if ( currentstate == RSS_DESCRIPTION){
            theString = new String(ch, theString.indexOf("<p>") + 3, theString.indexOf("</p>"));

        }
```

and the program just halts when it hits it.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!
-David

Comment: The substring code I just pasted is muddled from what I actually ran, I actually created a new String thisString and passed it theString instead of ch...

Comment: I don't think I believe the Log Cat dump.  Did the parser really change "South Korea..." to "SKorea..." or is there more to the XML?

Comment: @Brandon: Why don't you open the actual XML document, and see how it is structured? That might help you understand. It looks as though the "title" element is what contains SKorea, not the description.

Comment: Yeah I'm completely blind.  Didn't see the INFO/TITLE.  Where's the actual XML doc?

Comment: This is correct, the title tag is different from the description tag, and I logged both so I could reference which description should be there.

Comment: view-source:http://www.lamaruniversitypress.com/se/university-press-rss-1.1501466

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't reset `currentState` flag, since the SAX parser calls `characters` method chunk-by-chunk. And when the first chunk resets the flag, upcoming chars won't be processed the same way.

You can append char arrays to a `StringBuilder` and then flush it on any `startElement`, `endElement`, `processingInstruction` event.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain how `ch` is being set, so it's a bit hard to know what's going on. Here's my educated guess, though:

Many (if not all) SAX parsers will break up character data into separate events if things like entity references or CDATA sections appear within them. It looks like you're only handling the text from a single event. You want to concatenate them together.

Comment: public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)

Comment: sorry, ch is the character array passed to public void characters.

Comment: Oh, and they are being handled by a vector of rss objects, so in that way they are concatenated.

Comment: @david I don't know what you mean by "they are being handled by a vector of rss objects". From the little bit of code you've posted it looks like you're calling `_item.setDescription(theString)` where `theString` is just the characters passed to the the `characters` event handler method. Assuming `setDescription` does what its name implies, then that's wrong. You want to append to the description, not set it. Please post more code if you still need assistance.